# Is it possible to mine Litecoin with a MacBook?

Tags: scrypt, cpu-mining, gpu-mining

I have a MacBook and was told that I can't mine Litecoin with ASIC erupters. So, am I out of the loop with this whole new litecoins ordeal?

If so, can anything be done using my MacBook? I can get my hands on a PC laptop, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

For Litecoin and other scrypt coins, you'll generally be using either CPU or GPU mining.

However, laptops are NOT recommended for Litecoin or scrypt mining because they have inadequate cooling. The high temperatures generated during scrypt mining [can damage your laptop](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/19vupm/), costing you far more than what you could hope to earn from mining.

Even if you could work out the cooling issues, the CPUs or GPUs found in most notebooks are not fast enough to earn you a decent return.

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread, you should be able to use an ASIC Eruptor on a Mac.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=269929.0

Comment: You still can't use an erupter to mine Litecoins. Erupters can only mine SHA256d coins like Bitcoin and Namecoin. They can't mine scrypt coins like Litecoin.